# How to create a comma-delimited string from associative array's key-value pairs

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a quick way (maybe with a PHP built-in function) to create a comma-delimited string from associative array's key-value pairs?

For example I want this:

```
(array) ['key' => 'value', 'foo' => 'bar'];
```

to become:

```
(string) 'key=value, foo=bar'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str_replace('&', ', ',  http_build_query($arr));
```

Also we can set separator in http_build_query like this

```
http_build_query($arr, null, ', ');
```

If your array contains special chars

```
urldecode(http_build_query($arr, null, ', '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are the codes:

```
$string = '';
 foreach($array AS $key => $val){
     $string .= $key . '=' . $val . ',';
 }

$string = trim($string, ',');

 echo $string;
```

Where `$array` will be the array variable.

Hope it will work.

Comment: I made some edit. It will solve the problem now @AntonisGrigoriadis.

Comment: I do it the same way as William, then just use trim afterwards. It is easier than trying to deal with avoiding the last comma by catching the last item in the loop.